# Не работает Swagger при загрузки приложения на Azure, не может найти xml файл документации

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, azure, swagger

В ASP.NET Core проекте используется Swagger, приложение не может получить доступ к xml файлу документации. На другом хостинге все работает. На локальной машине все работает. Текст ошибки:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Web.xml'.
```

Вес трейс ошибки:

```
System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
FileShare share, int bufferSize, FileOptions options)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
FileShare share, int bufferSize)
System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, 
IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(string uri, XmlSpace space)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenOptions+<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<IncludeXmlComments>b__0() 
Swashbuckle .AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenOptions
.CreateSwaggerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
.SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateSwaggerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)  
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup
.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup
.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup
.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup
.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider+<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher
.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities
.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Код, который вызывает ошибку:

```
var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Web.xml");
c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

Настройки выходных данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вместо картинки приложите весь трейс ошибки, пожалуйста .

Comment: пробовали `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` или `AppContext.BaseDirectory` ?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor да, результат аналогичный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlatformServices [устарел](https://github.com/aspnet/PlatformAbstractions). Больше не нужно использовать его в новых проектах. Вы можете использовать его замену согласно ссылке на гитхаб.

Попробуйте заменить на

```
var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
```

**Update**

если не работает, то попробуйте этот вариант

```
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>  
{
var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

var assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(assemblyName + ".xml");
options.IncludeXmlComments(System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, fileName));

});
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант, ошибка та же. Засунул файл в нужный каталог вручную, это тоже не помогло. Возможно у меня просто нет прав на чтение файла

Comment: попробуйте вывести путь и файлы в этом директории. и скажите результат

Comment: Странное дело. Среди файлов по пути `D:\home\site\wwwroot\ ` есть файлы, которые я добавил вручную, вроде `appsettings.json`, но нет файла `Web.xml`, который лежит рядом с ним.

Comment: то есть в директории файл существует. а в программе вывели список файлов, и там нет web.xml?

Comment: Его нет после публикации, но если засунуть его в корень проекта и поставить параметры Действие при сборке: содержимое, Всегда копировать, то он будет загружен и ошибка исчезнет, но Swagger не будет работать, будет выдавать ошибку `Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.`

Comment: скорее всего не разрешен CORS. попробуйте [разрешить запросы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/cors)

Comment: Это не помогло к сожалению

Comment: Я понял в чем была проблема. Проблема была в браузере. Все работает без CORS в chrome, но не работает вообще в microsoft edge. Хотя при локальном запуске все работает и в microsoft edge.